# Locally scoped CSS (child components)

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, css-modules

Is there a way to have locally scoped CSS where I don't need to add a tag to every sub-component?

For example, using css modules, I want to do something like:

```
import style from "./MyStyles.module.scss";
```

And then:

```
<div className={style.componentA}>
  <img src="A.jpg" />
  <img src="B.jpg" />
  <img src="C.jpg" />
</div>
```

Where MyStyles.module.scss looks like:

```
.componentA {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    img {
      width: 50px;
      height: 100px;
    }
}
```

While that works for .componentA, the styles aren't propogating to the img components. Is there a way to do this without having to add something like `className={style.myImage}` to every img component?

Comment: What does the css output look like? That's pretty surprising behaviour

Comment: When you inspect the img element what are the css properties?